# Methods for comparing datasets for abnormalities

Tags: machine-learning, r, dataset, outlier

My team at work receives datasets from various companies each quarter, and we're wanting to build some sort of machine learning model that compares the new dataset to our existing data for any potential nonsensical values. What kinds of approaches would work for something like this? We're thinking of using R, but we also have Alteryx.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit about what do you mean by 'nonsensical values'? And what is the aim of the analysis? Just to compare them?

Comment: You might look into data validation tools, or write validation rules yourself. If you are using R, there are several assert packages, e.g. assertr, where you use rules to validate incoming data.